# Can't add Thickness to UV Sphere with Solidify

Tags: uv, solidify-modifier

New to blender, extremely new still. I just use it for 3D prints, but anyways. I'm trying to add thickness to my UV Sphere, but adding solidify to adjust the thickness ain't working at all. I've looked on Google, and I've followed YouTube videos cause I thought maybe I was doing something wrong, but I'm doing everything right according to the tutorials  Anyways, any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[image: Solidify Modifier currently added, with 2mm thickness. But no change to UV Sphere.]
Added Solidify Modifier with 2mm thickness. But no change to UV Sphere

Answer (score 2):

Your object is carrying a scale transform, assigned in Object Mode:

[image]

.. which is executed on the object (the 'vehicle' of your mesh,) *after* the mesh has been manipulated in Edit Mode, and subsequently by modifiers. So your *Solidify* is thickening a very large mesh by 2mm, and *then* scaling the whole lot down to 0.008 of its original size.

Fix: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Apply the scale, baking the Object scale into the mesh.

As a rule of thumb, never scale in Object Mode during modelling.